# Is there any way to get a web page to cut off at 100% width?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a problem where I have an Image which is supposed to overflow its container vertically, but my problem is that if it is close to the edge of the page it extends the page and has loads of white space on the right hand side.

Is there any way to cut off this white space? or to hide the horizontal side overflow but not vertical?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDKg5.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have tried this already, but how about:

overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.

I have tried this but it will remove the vertical overflow for some reason which is not what i want.

compare this http://i.imgur.com/hw44QPo.png to the one i posted before

EDIT : also adding overflow y visible did not fix it